# Can Verilator create a class hierarchy?

Tags: verilog, verilator

General `Verilator` question:

- When I specify a hierarchical Verilog design with multiple modules, split in several files, is the design then always flattened to a `single` c++ class or is there a possibility that `Verilator` retains the hierarchy by creating a class for each separate module ?

Comment: I have the same problem, I'm using --cc which according to documentation (https://www.veripool.org/ftp/verilator_doc.pdf, page 31) should create {prefix}{each_verilog_module}.cpp & .h C++ files for each module, but it doesn't.

I also try to force with --public :

/*verilator public_module*/
[...] indicate the module should not be inlined [...] so that C code may access the module. [...]  Also set for all modules when using the --public switch.

But it won't create classes either.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `// verilator public` will generate seperate classes. There is also a SystemVerilog `DPI-C` that lets you access the internal wires via `C`.

Comment: I'm using --public, and it doesn't generate separate classes :( ANy idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: @AlexandreDumont Try adding ```/*verilator public*/```  in the verilog code instead of ```option --public```.